# Trouble moving around multiple While loops

Tags: python-3.x

```
while ctr <=len(d)-1:
    latlong = re.findall(r'&amp;ll=(.*?)&amp;z=14', d[ctr], re.DOTALL)
    lat2, long2 = latlong[0].split(',')
    while ctra <=len(name)-1:
        if lat2 == lat[ctra] and long2 == long[ctra]:
            ctr = ctr +1
            break
        continue
        else:
            aname = re.findall(r'">(.*?)<' , d[ctr], re.DOTALL)
```

Simple problem is the lat2 and long2 matches I want to add one to the counter and then jump back up to the original While statement.  How do I do it.  This is my most recent attempt at and it isn't working.  I'm trying to check for multiple entries before putting an entry into the list.

I'm comparing latitude/longitude coordinates coming in from a website to ones that are already in the lat[ctra]/long[ctra].  If they don't match I want to continue with the next lat[ctra]/long[ctra] listing in the database.  All possible entries already in the database need to be checked against, quite naturally, until either a match is found or I have gone through the whole database.  Once all entries have been gone through then I want to add lat2/long2 to the database as well as the address, name, etc that goes with the coordinate.  I can add them in but I can't remove duplicate entries.

Comment: can you add a sample of your input data ? also your desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudocode :

```
outer_while :
    # do ya thing
    inner_while:
        if lat2 == long2 : 
            ctr += 1
            break
```